# How Can I Get Data From HTML Source Code with PHP and RegEx?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have got HTML source code, and i must get some information text in the HTML. I can not use DOM, because the document isn't well-formed.

Maybe, the source could change later, I can not be aware of this situation. So, the solution of this problem must be advisible for most situation.

Im getting source with curl, and i will edit it with preg_match_all function and regular expressions.

Source : 

...
`<TR Class="Head1">`

`<TD width="15%"><font size="12">Name</font></TD>`

`<TD>:&nbsp;</TD>`

`<TD align="center"><font color="red">Alex</font></TD>`

`<TD width="25%"><b>Job</b></TD>`

`<TD>:&nbsp;</B></TD>`

`<TD align="center" width="25%"><font color="red">Doctor</font></TD>`

`</TR>`

...

...

`<TR Class="Head2">`

`<TD width="15%" align="left">Age</B></TD>`

`<TD>:&nbsp;</TD>`

`<TD align="center"><font color="red">32</font></TD>`

`<TD width="15%"><font size="10">data</TD></font>`

`<TD>&nbsp;</B></TD>`

`<TD width="40%">&nbsp;</TD>`

`</TR>`

...

As we have seen, the source is not well-formed. In fact, terrible! But there is nothing I can do.
The source is longer than this.

How can I get the data from the source? I can delete all of HTML codes, but how can i know sequence of data? What can I do with preg_match_all and regex? What else can I do?

Im waiting for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to use `DOM`? You can suppress errors using `@` and even if it isn't well formed it still works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use the DOM this is far better than regexes. Take a look a [PHP Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) - it's designed to manage badly formed HTML.

Comment: +1 - I added PHP Tidy to my answer when I remembered that TagSoup is in Java (and this question is in PHP) but you had it in your answer first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOMDocument to load badly formed HTML:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML('<TR Class="Head2">
<TD width="15%" align="left">Age</B></TD>
<TD>:&nbsp;</TD>
<TD align="center"><font color="red">32</font></TD>
<TD width="15%"><font size="10">data</TD></font>
<TD>&nbsp;</B></TD>
<TD width="40%">&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>');


$tds = @$doc->getElementsByTagName('td');
foreach ($tds as $td) {
 echo $td->textContent, "\n";
}
```

I'm suppressing warnings in the above code for brevity.

Output:

```
Age
: 
32
data
  <!-- space -->
  <!-- space -->
```

Using regex to parse HTML can be a futile effort as HTML is not a regular language.

Comment: As you said, I think regex is not useful for this. Non-well-formed html document could be processed by Tidy and DOM, or only SimpleHTMLDom.

Answer (score 0):

[Don't use RegEx.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) The link is funny but not informative, so the long and short of it is that HTML markup is not a regular language, hence cannot be parsed simply using regular expressions.

You could use RegEx to parse individual 'tokens' ( a single open tag; a single attribute name or value...) as part of a recursive parsing algorithm, but you cannot use a magic RegEx to parse HTML all on its own.

Or you could use a parser.

Since the markup isn't valid, maybe you could use [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) or [PHP:Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).

Comment: Alright, are TagSoup and Tidy installed on server by default?

Comment: I'm not under the impression as such; as a matter of fact TagSoup is a Java tool (my bad!) although tidy is apparently [bundled with PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.installation.php)

Comment: Non-well-formed html document could convert to well-formed html by the Tidy, then DOMDocument could use.
Thx for all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = <<<EOF
<TR Class="Head2">\s+<TD width="15%" align="left">Age</B></TD>\s+<TD>:&nbsp;</TD>\s+<TD align="center"><font color="red">(\d+)</font></TD>\s+<TD width="15%"><font size="10">(\w+)</TD></font>\s+<TD>&nbsp;</B></TD>\s+<TD width="40%">&nbsp;</TD>\s+</TR>
EOF;

preg_match_all($regex, $text, $result);

var_dump($result)
```